# Know how many connections are open

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I'm using `vb.net` and `MSSQL Server` for my program, this program refresh the interface each 5 seconds so hit the database a lot and while more time the application is running the reactions are more slow, I need to check how many connections are open let say 10 minutes after the application start running. Is that posible using `vb.net`?.

Comment: Is there a problem with the number of connections?  If so, it might be better to show how you are using them

Comment: Look at Activity Monitor in SQL Server Studio, and you can monitor the connections there as your app runs.  Or if you're using Visual Studio 2017, you can run your app under the debugger and watch activity there as well.

Comment: @Plutonix I think that's the reason because the many refresh actions it mades.

Comment: Connections should be 'pooled' (and you should also be closing them). Use activity number to see what your query is waiting on. It could be an application side thing

Comment: Hmmm...not sure what that means but an *actual* refresh can be done with the dataadapter if you are using one.  Again, the issue is in the code that we cant see

Comment: There is also a class that will let the DB tell you when a table changes...cant recall the name: SqlDependency Class!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the newly programmers always `disregard` the `connections` to `close`, their goal is just to `run` the code without any `error returns`. In Short they forgot to `Close` the `database Connections` which is a `Very Important` on the Database side.

I am not sure if this is what you need.

```
SELECT   
    count(1) as connected
FROM sys.dm_exec_connections AS c  
JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions AS s  
    ON c.session_id = s.session_id  
WHERE c.session_id = @@SPID;
```

See this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-connections-transact-sql) for more info.

This runs only if you have an `Authorized Permission` to perform this action on the target Database.